# Question about chain complex of oriented simplical complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm reading Rotman's Introduction to algebraic topology and some question arises.

Let $K$ be an oriented simplicail complex ; i.e., a simplicial complex with a partial order on $\operatorname{Vert}(K)$ whose restriction to the vertices of any simplex in $K$ is a linear order.

In his book p.143, he defined $C_q(K)$ as follows :

[image]

Let $\rho := [p_0,\cdots , p_q], \sigma:= [p'_0, \cdots, p'_q] $ be $q$-simplexes in $K$.

My question is,

Q. If $<p_0,\cdots , p_q> = <p'_0, \cdots, p'_q>$, then $|\rho|\subseteq |\sigma|$ (underlying spaces) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

In the proof of Theorem 7.8 it is explained how to associate to an abstract simplicial complex complex $L$ a (Euclidean) simplicial complex $u(L)$. In particular, to each simplex $s =\{v_{i_0},\ldots, v_{i_q}\}$ of $L$ we associate to simplex $\lvert s \rvert = [e_{i_0},\ldots, e_{i_q}]$.

In Lemma 7.10 $K$ is an abstract simplicial complex with a partial order of its vertices such that the restriction to the vertices of any simplex in $K$ is a linear order.

Now you consider two $q$-simplices $\rho = \{p_0,\ldots , p_q\}, \sigma= \{p'_0, \ldots, p'_q\}$ in $K$. Be aware that the expressions $[p_0,\ldots , p_q], [p'_0, \ldots, p'_q]$ do not make sense here, they can only be used in Euclidean simplicial complexes. Also note that no vertex is repeated in $\rho, \sigma$ (otherwise they would be simplices of dimension $< q$).

The elements $<p_0,\ldots , p_q>, <p'_0, \ldots, p'_q>$ are the equivalence classes in $C_q(K)$ of the sequences $(p_0,\ldots , p_q), (p'_0, \ldots, p'_q)$ and $<p_0,\ldots , p_q> = <p'_0, \ldots, p'_q>$ means that $p_i' = p_{\pi(i)}$ for some permutation $\pi$. Thus $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are associated to the convex hulls $|\rho|$ and $|\sigma|$ of *the same $q+1$ points*, possible written in distinct order. This means $|\rho| =|\sigma|$.

Comment: O.K. It seems that key observation is considerting abstract simplicial complex and the convex hulls $|\rho|$ and $|\sigma|$ are of same $q+1$ points. Thanks ~~